# ParseUser setReadAccess security issue

Tags: facebook, security, parse-platform

In my app I would like to limit the permissions of the data my users are saving to only the logged-in user's Facebook friends. so for each row I need to set read permission to only Facebook friends. but to do so I need to get the Facebook friends' ParseUser(s)... if I have the ability to fetch all ParseUsers, It's already a big security issue because it means each user can know about all other users.

Is there a proper solution for that?

Thanks

Comment: You could lock down security on the client end and look to using Cloud Code with the master key to run your logic to get the data you need per your security requirements.

Comment: makes a lot of sense:).
Thanks for that. I was looking for something in the client side...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that there are only 2 options to solve this:
1. As suggested in the comments above using a cloud code.
2. Create additional entity and share there only what you want to share. while limit access to the users entity entirely.

Thanks.